# Identify transistors for 4x20 LED matrix in order to find replacement

Tags: mosfet, identification

[image: highlighted graphics][image: whole board]I have a bunch of LED lights (no schematics available) that have a bad transistor and new fixtures are prohibitively expensive ($100 each!) so I'd like to just replace the transistors. What company uses the logo seen on the transistor? The number 2N60 brings up a lot of transistors but none of them have any of the other numbers seen on my transistor. When I test the output on a light plate that is working, I get around 22 VDC. The numbers on the transistor are: "ORG2N60"  "613G" and "0581" I used heat transfer paste to highlight the letters and logo on this transistor.

[image]

Comment: what is printed on the transistors ... some of us cannot view pictures ... please add to the question ... DO NOT add in comment

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsMZ0.jpg

Comment: Logo is rubbed out

Comment: Clues are best with the whole board

Comment: Looks like a G2N60.  The rest of the numbers are probably lot/date codes and do not need to match.

Comment: no letters or number subs match... custom. nobody even matches that mold for the TO-263 D2PAK  but probably a dual 30A diode

Comment: uploaded a picture of the whole board

Comment: The guess is that it is a 2A 60V mosfet. Probably from some non-descript Chinese manufacturer. Lcsc.com might be a good place to search. There’s probably a number of parts with similar ratings that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a MOSFET, probably N-channel 2A/600V.

From the logo, it is made by [Changdian](https://www.esmchina.com/news/201707211605.html) (长电科技), a major Chinese semiconductor manufacturer.

A suitable replacement would be the [Alpha & Omega AOD2N60A](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOD2N60A.pdf).